# Put a shortcut under Windows Quick access list?

Tags: windows, delphi

I need to put a shortcut programmatically under Quick access list, just like DropBox and OneDrive did, see the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2nw8.jpg.

Is there any documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply creating a shortcut to specific folder inside `C:\Users\YourUserName\Links`

This works on Windows 7. I need to test this on Windows 10.

EDIT: This method does not work on Windows 10